# php - How do I get rid of this strange "empty delimiter" message

Tags: php

I have some code that uses the stristr function to extract data I need.

It gives me this Warning for every iteration of the loop:

```
Warning: stristr() [function.stristr]: Empty delimiter in ... line 55
```

The code works apart from this Warning.  Here is the code:

```
$data = stristr("$text", "$key");
$result = string_limit_words($data,2);
print "$result<BR>";
```

How do I get rid of the warning message?

Comment: Go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php and search for Empty delimiter. There's comments there and it's variable to what version of PHP you're using.

Comment: note: $data = stristr("$text", "$key"); invokes extra parsing than $data = stristr($text, $key);

Comment: @ Steve, but the manual didn't help with this one, hence me asking here. @ Dan thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$data = $text;
if($key)
   $data = stristr($data, $key);
$result = string_limit_words($data,2);
print "$result<BR>";
```

Basically only do the stristr if the $key (the needle) is not an empty string

Comment: Thanks. I believe there was one empty $key that spoiled it for the rest!

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't shown us the loop. I assume that the code you posted is in the body of the loop
2. Why use "$variable" ? Quotationmarks are not required here.
3. You can suppress warnings by writing @functionName();
4. Check if the needle is empty before applying it
5. HTML (< BR>) should be lowercase

Comment: -1 you didn't answer his question, suggested suppressing warnings as the solution, and nagged about a bunch of other stuff that wasn't central to the problem.

Comment: @Steven Oxley: Actually, he did answer the question at point #4.

Comment: Well, number 4 is indeed the problem. and empty (as in "" ) will throw this error. Null will return false, incidentally. (jan, just make number 4 number one, eh?)

Comment: @Dan Heberden: Which would also make #2 correct, because the quotes make it an empty string instead of NULL (unless the variable is specifically defined to be an empty string before this).

Comment: @Steven Oxley I was in the process of editing while you were downvoting. :)

Comment: @Jan Kuboschek OK, OK, I didn't realize and I have attempted to remove my downvote, but apparently you made the edit after my downvote got processed (in other words, while I was reading the answer) because it says I can't change my vote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @animuson - good point! - and i bet you that was his issue, too

Answer (score 1):

**Quote from php.net stristr user: dpatton.at.confluence.org**

There was a change in PHP 4.2.3 that can cause a warning message
to be generated when using stristr(), even though no message was
generated in older versions of PHP.

The following will generate a warning message in 4.0.6 and 4.2.3:

```
stristr("haystack", "");
```

OR

```
$needle = "";  
stristr("haystack", $needle);
```

This will *not* generate an "Empty Delimiter" warning message in
4.0.6, but *will* in 4.2.3:

```
unset($needle); 
stristr("haystack", $needle);
```

[Here's a URL](http://groups.google.ca/groups?selm=cvshholzgra1031224321@cvsserver) that documents what was changed